# NullPointerException when moving with cursor (SQLite) in a switch statement

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor, nullpointerexception

So I am getting a NullPointerException every time I click on any of the buttons. For some reason, when I am in the switch statement, I get an error. My DB helper class simply returns a cursor and so I am using that Cursor in my specific activity. I just want to be able to switch between DB entries back and forth depending on the user preferences. And I also want to display different elements of the row and not the whole row. Any suggestions will be appreciated. I thought that this method will provide what I need but I can't get it to work.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SQLView extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    /* these 3 variables are the same as in the Database class */
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_FRONT = "card_front";
    public static final String KEY_BACK = "card_back";

    /* variables are made global so we can use them in all of our functions here */
    private Cursor myCursor;
    private TextView tv;
    private int iRow;
    private int iFront;
    private int iBack;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sqlview);

        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSQLinfo);
        String result = null;
        Flashcards info = new Flashcards(this);
        info.open();


        myCursor = info.getCursor();
        //info.close();

        iRow = myCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        iFront = myCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_FRONT);
        iBack = myCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_BACK);

        Button front = (Button) findViewById(R.id.front);
        Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        Button prev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prev);

        front.setOnClickListener(this);
        back.setOnClickListener(this);
        next.setOnClickListener(this);
        prev.setOnClickListener(this);


        myCursor.moveToFirst();
        //Set the TextView to be the first card in our database 
        tv.setText(myCursor.getString(iFront));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        /* check if we are at our last entry in the DB */
        if(myCursor.isAfterLast()){
            /* move our cursor back to the first entry */
            myCursor.moveToFirst();
        }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.front:
                tv.setText(myCursor.getString(iFront));
                break;

            case R.id.back:
                tv.setText(myCursor.getString(iBack));
                break;

            case R.id.next:
                if(myCursor.moveToNext()){
                    tv.setText(myCursor.getString(iFront));
                }else{
                    myCursor.moveToFirst();
                }
                break;

            case R.id.prev:
                myCursor.moveToPrevious();
                tv.setText(myCursor.getString(iFront));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line exactly throws the NPE?

Comment: any line of the switch statement where I am setting the text field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local variable `tv` in `onCreate` doesnt actually get assigned to the class member variable of the same name resulting in an `NPE` in the `switch` statement. Replace

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSQLinfo);
```

with

```
tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSQLinfo);
```

Comment: Reimeus, Thank you so very much! It worked right away... I love it when the problem is only a few letters long and a simple delete will fix it!! Thank you sir!